# tinyMCE dropdown menu disconnected from 'add hyperlink' modal

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, tinymce

I am working on a project bug where my tinyMCE 'Add Hyperlink' dropdown isn't showing up unless I'm zoomed out to at least 67% (Chrome). I see that there's a dynamically added inline style on the dropdown menu container but I don't know where it's being applied, and I've combed through as many files as I can. I can see in the tinyMCE code where other types of declarations are made, like how the menus are formatted, etc, but nothing to show me where this particular I am using tinyMCE 4.7.7, the link & anchor plugins, Bootstrap 3 & jQuery in a C# MVC project. I previously had issues between two projects having inconsistent bugs due to different versions of tinyMCE's jQuery, so that is a possibility. Any help or ideas are appreciated - thank you!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHIyo.png): [image: tinyMCE add link disconnected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging, it turns out there was a `.mce-menu {position: relative;}` that was overriding the `position: absolute` that determined the dropdown's appearance. Solved my own problem!